# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: no such table: user

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a simple web app, where users can register. I have created SQLite database. The problem is that, app can't detect table in database, but querying works just fine.

[query] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYmi4.png)

[error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfoEr.png)

[DB] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Oop.png)

> I have seen, same questions, but none of them works for me. If I put db.create_all(), I won't get error, but it won't insert data into DB (if I insert same email, it won't recognize that I already registered this mail and I can't see it in query).

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class user(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)


@app. route ('/')
def index ():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app. route ('/register', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def register ():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        first_name = request.form['firstName']
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        # Check if email already exists
        User = user.query.filter_by(email=email). first ()
        if User:
            return render_template('register.html', error='Email address already in use')

        # Check if passwords match
        if password1 != password2:
            return render_template('register.html', error='Passwords do not match')

        # Create new user

        db.session.add(
            user(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256')))
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('register.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your database each time you add new models, in `flask` that is done by **Flask-Migrate** module, so these are the steps you need to do:

1. `pip install Flask-Migrate`
2. `flask db init`
3. `flask db migrate -m "Initial migration."`
4. `flask db upgrade`

After that your database should contain the necessary tables and your code should work fine.

More on the topic here:
https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: it did not work

Comment: this is how my console looks 
`
[07/Mar/2023 19:29:06] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[07/Mar/2023 19:28:57] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[07/Mar/2023 19:29:06] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
`

Comment: you seem to have redundant spacebars in your view, on this line: `User = user.query.filter_by(email=email). first ()` try removing them first

Comment: it's just this website formatting